# RSS Viewer Customization to remove some of the text rendered - SharePoint 2010

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, rss-reader

I am trying to customize the way the items from an RSS feed is displayed in my RSS viewer web part. I would like to prevent the web part from showing everything after the ellipses (...). For example the text below is the description from my test RSS Viewer Page using the Google News RSS feed:

New Hampshire Visit Offers Glimpse Into Possible Walker, Bush Rivalry
NPR
The two likely Republican presidential front-runners, Wisconsin Gov. Scott Walker and former Florida Gov. Jeb Bush, visited New Hampshire this weekend. Though neither has officially declared their candidacy, The Boston Globe's James Pindell says they're ...
Here's what Jeb is saying when people ask him about the Bush dynastyBusinessinsider India
No longer under the radar, Jeb Bush to tour the state Capitol on ThursdayAtlanta Journal Constitution (blog)
Scott Walker PAC: Jeb Bush is not the only one who can raise moneyCNN International
New Hampshire Public Radio -Petoskey News-Review
all 82 news articles »

I would like to remove everything after the "..." and hence the page would then display :

New Hampshire Visit Offers Glimpse Into Possible Walker, Bush Rivalry NPR The two likely Republican presidential front-runners, Wisconsin Gov. Scott Walker and former Florida Gov. Jeb Bush, visited New Hampshire this weekend. Though neither has officially declared their candidacy, The Boston Globe's James Pindell says they're ...

I haven't really worked with XSLT or XML in the past and hence this is proving quite difficult for me. I have asked a similar question on SharePoint StackExchange but no response yet so I thought I would post on here as well.Thanks for any help.

**Edit**
Below is the code:

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%-- _lcid="1033" _version="14.0.7006" _dal="1" --%>
<%-- _LocalBinding --%>
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" title="loc:TitleBar" id="TitleBar" AllowLayoutChange="false" AllowPersonalization="false"><ZoneTemplate>
    <WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" AllowEdit="True" AllowConnect="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Title="Web Part Page Title Bar" IsIncluded="True" Dir="Default" IsVisible="True" AllowMinimize="False" ExportControlledProperties="True" ZoneID="TitleBar" ID="g_ebad7959_96e5_4485_b67a_ff43ff07343b" HeaderTitle="BlogTestPage" AllowClose="False" FrameState="Normal" ExportMode="All" AllowRemove="False" AllowHide="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" DetailLink="" ChromeType="None" HelpLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageSmall="" HelpMode="Modeless" FrameType="None" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="2" Description="" PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{EBAD7959-96E5-4485-B67A-FF43FF07343B}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
    Div.ms-titleareaframe {
    height: 100%;
    }
    .ms-pagetitleareaframe table {
    background: none;
    }
  </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
// ]]>
    </script>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent ID="WebPartPageHideQLStyles" UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
<style type="text/css">
body #s4-leftpanel {
    display:none;
}
.s4-ca {
    margin-left:0px;
}
</style>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
        ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
    <div height="100%" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="10" height="1" alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
        <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate>
                    <WpNs0:RSSAggregatorWebPart runat="server" Description="Displays an RSS feed." ListDisplayName="" ImportErrorMessage="Cannot import this web part." PartOrder="2" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="True" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="RSS Viewer" ViewFlag="0" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" CacheXslTimeOut="600" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="All" Dir="Default" DetailLink="" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" EnableOriginalValue="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" ViewContentTypeId="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" ExpandFeed="True" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this web part." HelpMode="Modeless" FeedUrl="http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&amp;cf=all&amp;ned=us&amp;hl=en&amp;output=rss" ListUrl="" ID="g_fd7ba5cc_29e7_4892_9305_3857422aa65a" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{FD7BA5CC-29E7-4892-9305-3857422AA65A}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
                        <ParameterBinding Name="RequestUrl" Location="WPProperty[FeedUrl]"/>
                    </ParameterBindings>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt" 
               xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
               xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
               xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart"
               xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
               xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
               xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
               xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

    <xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">false</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="rss" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>



        <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="atom2:feed">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >            
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                        <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(channel/link))}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/>
                        </a>
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>



        <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                    <div class="item link-item" >
                            <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </div>                            
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- some RSS2.0 contain pubDate tag, some others dc:date -->
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(pubDate) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="pubDateLength" select="string-length(pubDate) - 3" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(substring(pubDate,0,$pubDateLength),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(description) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="description"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:if>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>





        <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="rss1:item"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:channel/rss1:link))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="rss1:channel/rss1:title"/>
                </a>
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                    <div class="item link-item" >
                        <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="rss1:title"/>
                        </a>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(rss1:description) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="rss1:description"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:if>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:link))}">More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom:entry"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
                </a>
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                            <div class="item link-item" >
                                <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
                                </a>
                                <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                        <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                        <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:summary) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:summary"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:content) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:content"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom2:entry"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">                
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                     <div class="item link-item" >
                                <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
                                </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom2:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:summary) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:summary"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:content) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:content"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:param name="Html"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</Xsl>
<DataSources>
<SharePoint:XmlUrlDataSource runat="server" HttpMethod="GET" SelectCommand="" AuthType="None" XPath=""><DataFileParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="RequestUrl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" Name="RequestUrl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
</DataFileParameters>
</SharePoint:XmlUrlDataSource>
</DataSources>
</WpNs0:RSSAggregatorWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
                </tr>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</script>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Without seeing any code or input, we can hardly help you.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I just made updates to my post and included code. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good start. Now please explain which RSS feed serves as your input document.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - unless I'm misinterpreting your question but I'm using the google news rss feed for my example (http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss)

Comment: That's fine thanks - exactly what I meant.

Comment: The text about "Stockholm" is not currently part of that RSS document - can you please give an example that contains text I can find?

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I just edited my original post to include a recent news item from the feed. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, difficult to say without knowledge of SP, but the text you are interested in is inside `description`. The text content of `description` (escaped HTML) is processed by the `<xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">` template, which calls `rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)` - which we don't see. Perhaps it would be easier to wair for someone who knows Sharepoint - and this likelihood would increase if you tagged the question with sharepoint.